# Running Google Cloud SQL Proxy on Raspberry

Tags: json, raspberry-pi, google-cloud-sql

I'm getting an error while trying to connect raspberry running ubuntu mate to my Google Cloud SQL instance.

These are the step I did to install:

```
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy
cd cloudsql-proxy/
sudo sh download_proxy.sh
```

My instance is configured this way (I deleted some characters in the image and in the code):
[image: Instance]

I didn't set the network because I'll be using proxy

Then I download into the same folder my JSON key.

```
wget https://drive.google.com/file/d/my_key.json
```

And the start the proxy

```
sudo ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=be   -     21:us-central1:be   =tcp:3306 \
                  -credential_file=./my_key.json &
```

But I'm getting the error:

> pi@pi:~/cloudsql-proxy$ ./cloud_sql_proxy: 1: ./cloud_sql_proxy:
>   Syntax error: ")" unexpected

I've tried removing the .json and I was getting the same error before without credential, I think that the problem is in the setup.

My dir ls is:
[image: dir ls]

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe cloud_sql_proxy didn't get downloaded properly? Try opening the file in a text editor, it sounds like the file doesn't have the right contents.

Comment: Hi. I can't because it's an executable :(

Comment: Did you try? Based on the error you are getting there's something fishy with the file. What happens when you run `file cloud_sql_proxy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.

I'm sharing what I did to make it work, as David I don't know what version was I downloading.

I tried to avoid installing Go but it was the only way to get it installed.

```
sudo apt-get install golang-go
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
go get github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/cmd/cloud_sql_proxy
cd $GOPATH/bin
wget your_key.json
sudo ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=the_full_name_of_the_instance=tcp:3306 -credential_file=./your_key.json &
```

But I was getting a error because I already have mysql running localy in the same port

So now I'm using a unix soquet

```
sudo ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=the_full_name_of_the_instance -credential_file=./your_key.json &
```

And then it's ready for connections :)

Thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

`download_proxy.sh` downloads the proxy compiled for the amd64 architecture of CPU (aka x86_64). Your raspberry Pi has a ARM CPU, so this binary cannot run on your machine.

Google does not provide pre-build ARM versions of the proxy. I don't even know if it is able to build on ARM CPU. If it is possible, this is how you must do it:

1. Install `go`, e.g. with `apt-get install golang`
2. Setup a GOPATH, as per https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GOPATH
3. Run `go get github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/cmd/cloud_sql_proxy`
4. Run the proxy with `$GOPATH/cloud_sql_proxy -instances=...`

Answer (score 0):

I found issues with this when compiling SQL-proxy. I did, however, find the [instructions here](https://gist.github.com/simoncos/49463a8b781d63b5fb8a3b666e566bb5) worked great on my raspberry pi 3. Have to make sure to remove all prior installations then reinstall it

```
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.9.linux-armv6l.tar.gz
sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.9.linux-armv6l.tar.gz
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin # put into ~/.profile`
```